# What would the maximum energy density of a power source based on carbon-14

Tags: electrochemistry, energy, nuclear-chemistry

Various ways of generating electricity from small radioactive power sources have been long known.

The Voyager space probes launched in the 1970s use thermoelectric generation from plutonium sources to generate ~100W of power to keep the probes running when they go very far from the sun. Some small devices have used other sources and other conversion mechanisms to prove power for very low power applications [like pacemakers](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2015/ph241/degraw2/) where long lasting power that doesn't need to be replaced is an advantage.

But recent claims suggest a breakthrough where devices powered by carbon-14 could replace the batteries in mobile phones ([Nano diamond Batteries web page](https://ndb.technology/news/) highlights stories claiming their produces could "revolutionise mobile phone batteries").

These claims seem like uncritical hype but should be easy to check.

Ignoring engineering issues (like conversion efficiency) how does the energy density of a power source based on C-14 compare to a mobile phone battery?

(I'm guessing a simple calculation based on the radioactive properties of C-14 could give a decent answer and that any battery experts can tell us what a Li-ion battery achieves so we can compare them. Also, nuclear power sources are not "batteries" but they are compact power sources so please don't be distracted by the terminology).

Comment: The isotopic power of C-14 is 0.001305 W/g. That should be the theoretical upper limit even for an ideal system.

Comment: Some energy would be carried away by electron antineutrinos. For given thermal energy, the efficiency of energy conversion by Seeback effect thermocouples  in space probes (usually with $\ce{^{238}Pu}$ with $\pu{0.57 W/g}$)  is reportedly like 10%. There are prototypes using the Stirling engine with up to 40% efficiency, but with doubts about the long term reliability due moving parts.

Comment: Furthermore, the specific activity of C-14 is 1.6485E+11 Bq/g and the exemption limit is 1E+7 Bq. This gives you another limit if you do not want a safety license to be required for such a battery.

Comment: @Poutnik neutrinos are excluded from the value I gave above; so it's the energy available to the decay heat problem.

Comment: @Loong That's exactly the sort of data needed: A kg of C-14 would produce about a watt, which is less than the peak consumption rate of a typical mobile phone even if conversion were perfect. Do you have the calculation behind the W/g number or is it just a well-known fact?

Comment: @matt_black When calculating myself: The half life of C-14 is 5700 a, which gives you a decay constant of 3.853E-12/s or 2.321E+12 Bq/mol or 1.657E+11 Bq/g. The maximum beta energy is 0.15648 MeV, but the mean beta energy is only 0.04945 MeV = 7.923E-15 J. So the isotopic power is 1.657E+11 Bq/g * 7.923E-15 J = 1.313E-03 W/g. The value given by my old _Nuclides 2000_ is 1.3050E-03 W/g.

Comment: BTW, the title speaks about energy density, but the body and comments rather about power density. // It is better to call related quantities as specific energy/gravimetric energy density (J/kg), specific power/gravimetric power density (W/kg),  energy density/volumetric energy density (J/m3), power density/volumetric power density W/m3).

Comment: @Poutnik I'm happy to be corrected on the appropriate terminology to use for the comparison with conventional batteries. I suspect the relevant one is gravimetric power density in this case. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just a summary: as @Loong and others state, the *theoretical* maximum power would be ~1 mW/g. If the phone requires ~1 W average for transmit (if I remember correctly,cell phones can use ~4W for talking to more distant towers), 1 kg of C14 would be needed in a 100% efficient cell. Not only would it be heavy, keeping the 156 kV *beta* particles contained would take some heavy shielding. On the other hand, you would not need a night-light.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The maximum range of the 156.48 keV beta radiation from C-14 in plastic is less than 1 mm. No heavy shielding is required.

Comment: @Loong, the *beta* particles *themselves* are short range, but the Bremsstrahlung radiation produced by their stopping, i.e., **hard x-rays**, is *quite* a bit more penetrating!  https://physicsopenlab.org/2017/08/02/bremsstrahlung-radiation/ . Consider that color CRT's, using acceleration of just 40 kV or so, required heavy leaded-glass screens -- upt to 2 kg of Pb! https://computer.howstuffworks.com/question678.htm

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's correct. That's why you use low-z material like plastic for the shielding of pure beta radiation so that the contribution of hard x-rays is significantly reduced. The fraction of the beta energy released as bremsstrahlung is then only maybe 0.02 %. The dose rate from a 1E+13 Bq source in 1 m distance without additional shielding of x-rays would be about 0.04 mSv/h. No problem in a controlled area, but certainly not suitable for public use.

Answer (score 6):

The maximum theoretical power density of isotopically pure $\ce{^14C}$ can be estimated from the nuclear decay data of $\ce{^14C}$ as follows.

The half-life of $\ce{^14C}$ is $T_{1/2}=5.70\cdot 10^3\ \mathrm a$ [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224248235_Survey_on_Energy_Consumption_Entities_on_the_Smartphone_Platform/figures?lo=1). Thus, the corresponding decay constant is
$$\tau=\frac{\ln2}{T_{1/2}}=3.9\cdot 10^{-12}\ \mathrm s^{-1}$$
and the molar activity is
$$A_\mathrm M=\tau N_\mathrm A=2.3\cdot 10^{12}\ \mathrm{Bq\ mol^{-1}}$$
Since the molar mass of $\ce{^14C}$ is $M=14.0\ \mathrm{g\ mol^{-1}}$, the specific activity of $\ce{^14C}$ is
$$a=\frac{A_\mathrm M}M=1.7\cdot 10^{11}\ \mathrm{Bq\ g^{-1}}$$

The energy of the beta decay of $\ce{^14C}$ is $E=156.48\ \mathrm{keV}$ [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224248235_Survey_on_Energy_Consumption_Entities_on_the_Smartphone_Platform/figures?lo=1). However, the beta spectrum is continuous because the total energy of the decay process is divided between the electron, the antineutrino, and the recoiling nuclide. The mean beta energy only amounts to $E_\mathrm\beta=49.45\ \mathrm{keV}$ [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224248235_Survey_on_Energy_Consumption_Entities_on_the_Smartphone_Platform/figures?lo=1).

[image: C-14 beta spectrum]

Since
$$E_\mathrm\beta=49.45\ \mathrm{keV}=7.923\cdot 10^{-15}\ \mathrm J$$
the power density (so-called isotopic power) of $\ce{^14C}$ is
$$e_\mathrm\beta=aE_\mathrm\beta=1.3\cdot 10^{-3}\ \mathrm{W\ g^{-1}}$$

**How does this compare to a typical mobile phone battery?**

An iPhone 14 pro has a Li-ion battery with capacity of about 3,200 mAh. At a voltage of 3.6 V, this gives a capacity of about 11.5 Wh.

It weighs just over 200g. While the power consumption varies a lot depending on what the phone is doing these [have been estimated](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224248235_Survey_on_Energy_Consumption_Entities_on_the_Smartphone_Platform/figures?lo=1) to peak at over 4W for some other smartphones. We can estimate the average power consumption by noting that a typical iPhone needs to be recharged every one or two days. 11.5 Wh over a 48h time period suggests an average power consumption of about 240mW.

To provide the *average* power (ignoring conversion efficiency and any other engineering issues) this would require about 185g of C-14. But to provide the *peak* power (say 4W) would require more than 3kg of C-14 which is 15 times heavier than the *total* weight of an existing iPhone 14 pro.

This would be truly a revolution in mobile phone batteries, but not the good sort.

---

### References

[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224248235_Survey_on_Energy_Consumption_Entities_on_the_Smartphone_Platform/figures?lo=1) [ICRP Publication 107. Nuclear Decay Data for Dosimetric Calculations. *Ann. ICRP* **2008**, *38* (3).](https://www.icrp.org/publication.asp?id=ICRP%20Publication%20107)

Comment: Overall efficiency after accounting for the isotope separation is pretty lousy…

Comment: By way of comparison: 100 g C-14 is about 1.7E+13 Bq which approximately corresponds to the annual C-14 production of a CANDU reactor. The global atmospheric inventory of C-14 from natural sources is about 1.4E+15 Bq or 8.4 kg.